# Why do I get " parent key not found "

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

is there any reason why I get this error. I really searched this site before posting this question. I commented out some of my earlier tries.

What I implemented is Many to One connection.
So, PersonAccount has a BankId column (FK), while Bank knows nothing about PersonAccount. There is FK constraint implemented on database level.

```
        public BankMap()
        {
            Table("Bank");
            Not.LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).Column("BankId").GeneratedBy.Sequence("BANK_SEQ");
            Map(x => x.BankName);
            HasMany(x => x.PersonAccounts).KeyColumn("BANKID").Cascade.All();

            //HasMany(x => x.PersonAccounts).KeyColumn("BANKID").Cascade.All().Inverse();
            //HasMany(x => x.PersonAccounts).KeyColumn("BANKID").Cascade.All().None();
       //     HasMany(x => x.PersonAccounts)
       //.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
       //.KeyColumn("BANKID");

        }

public PersonAccountMap()
        {
            Table("PersonAccounts");
            Not.LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).Column("AccountId").GeneratedBy.Sequence("PERSONACCOUNTS_SEQ");
            Map(x=>x.PersonName);
            References(x => x.Bank, "BANKID");

            //References(x => x.Person, "PERSONID").Cascade.None();

        }
```

Hope you'll be able to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change BankMap to have:

```
HasMany(x => x.PersonAccounts).KeyColumn("BANKID").Inverse();
```

Then the Bank will not update PersonAccounts.

One more hint, from my own experience (you don't need to do it), I tend to rebuild project after changes in mapping as I found occasionally mapping project in VS wasn't build correctly with my latest changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's 6PM here in Bosnia and Herzegovina. I'll notify you about results tomorrow

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't  help

Comment: I am puzzled that it doesn't work, Obviously you have all inheritance set up: BankMap:ClassMap<Bank> and PersonAccountMap : ClassMap<PersonAccount>. Pleas let me know what was the problem.